# Why is my MySQL date displaying as blank in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, date

One of the fields in my database is of 'DATE' Type (field-name = 'post_date').

after fetching an array

```
$record = mysql_fetch_array($queryResult);
```

if I do

```
echo $record['post_date'];
```

I do not get any output (blank).

What should I do to properly handle the date type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a blank output from doing that (and your query is non-broken), the problem is that the column value is NULL, not that there's anything wrong with the PHP interaction.

Comment: thanks! true
the field was showing null ( i don't know why) because i remember entering it in thru phpMyAdmin.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Are you sure the fieldname is right, and that there's data in there?

As an aside: Dates are handled differently in MySQL and PHP:

- PHP stores dates as unix time, i.e. number of seconds since 00:00:00 on Jan 1st, 1970.
- MySQL stores them as Strings, like humans read them.

You can use the MySQL `from_unixtime()` and `unix_timestamp()` functions to convert back and forth as required.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to parse a MySQL DATE or DATETIME field into a UNIX timestamp is by using [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime).